# Flatten multi-level folder tree structure leaving only 'file'-type items in the output

Tags: javascript

I have an array like below in which there are two types of data, `file` or `folder`. I only want to filter `file` type data.

```
let data = [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "type": "file",
      "url": "www.first.com"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "type": "file",
      "url": "www.second.com"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "type": "folder",
      "items": [
          {
            "id": 6,
            "type": "file",
            "url": "www.third.com"
          }
       ]
    }
];
```

Desired result is

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "type": "file",
        "url": "www.first.com"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "type": "file",
        "url": "www.second.com"
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "type": "file",
        "url": "www.third.com"
    }
]
```

NOTE: There can be multiple levels like inside folder items, there can be another folder

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your folder structure may span few levels deep, you may need to traverse your input array recursively to *flatten* the tree structure, [`Array.prototype.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) may come in handy for that:

```js
const src = [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "type": "file",
      "url": "www.first.com"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "type": "file",
      "url": "www.second.com"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "type": "folder",
      "items": [
          {
            "id": 6,
            "type": "folder",
            "items" : [
              {
                "id" : 7,
                "type" : "file",
                "ulr" : "www.third.com"
              }
            ]
          }
       ]
    }
],

    flattenArr = arr => 
      arr.flatMap(({items=[], ...rest}) => 
        rest.type == 'folder' ? flattenArr(items) : rest)
      
      
console.log(flattenArr(src))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Recursive function that will traverse items if it exists.  Returns all files and flattens the arrays using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).  Ignores all other types.

```js
let data = [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "type": "file",
      "url": "www.first.com"
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "type": "file",
      "url": "www.second.com"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "type": "folder",
      "items": [
          {
            "id": 6,
            "type": "file",
            "url": "www.third.com"
          }
       ]
    }
];
walk = node =>
  node.type === 'file' ? node : (node.items||[]).flatMap(walk)

console.log(data.flatMap(walk))
```

Comment: I'm not sure why someone has downvoted. That looks like a nice solution. So, upvoted to restore the balance ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `.flatMap()` along with `.filter()` function to do this.

**P.S.** This solution will work only 1 level deep, i.e. if you have file type objects inside a folder. See the edited part of the answer for the solution that will filter file type objects from nested folders inside folders.

```js
let data = [
    { "id": 3, "type": "file", "url": "www.first.com" }, 
    { "id": 4, "type": "file", "url": "www.second.com" },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "type": "folder",
      "items": [
          { "id": 6, "type": "file", "url": "www.third.com" }
       ]
    }
];

const output = data.flatMap(a => {
  return a.type === 'file' 
          ? a
          : a.items.filter(item => item.type === 'file');  
});

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

### EDIT:

Here's a recursive solution that will filter objects of type `files` from nested folders

```js
let data = [
    { "id": 3, "type": "file", "url": "www.first.com" }, 
    { "id": 4, "type": "file", "url": "www.second.com" },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "type": "folder",
      "items": [
          { "id": 6, "type": "file", "url": "www.third.com" },
          {
            "id": 7,
            "type": "folder",
            "items": [
               { "id": 8, "type": "file", "url": "www.fourth.com" },
               {
                 "id": 9,
                 "type": "folder",
                 "items": [
                   { "id": 10, "type": "file", "url": "www.fifth.com" }
                 ]
              }
            ]
          }
       ]
    }
];

function filterFiles(arr) {
  return arr.flatMap(item => item.type === 'file' ? item : filterFiles(item.items));
}

console.log(filterFiles(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use basic implementation of going through nested arrays.

Accumulate objects into the list if the object with type file is found.

```js
let data = [{
  "id": 3,
  "type": "file",
  "url": "www.first.com"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "type": "file",
  "url": "www.second.com"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "type": "folder",
  "items": [{
    "id": 6,
    "type": "file",
    "url": "www.third.com"
  }]
}];


function recursive(arr) {
  const list = []
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] && arr[i].items && Array.isArray(arr[i].items)) {
      return [...list, ...recursive(arr[i].items)];
    }
    if (arr[i] && arr[i].type === 'file') {
      list.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return list;

}

console.log(recursive(data))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data.filter(each => each.type === "file");
```

That will give you what you want